# In Debian11, how to optimize Pyqt5 QPixmap to improve the efficiency of real-time display images

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, debian

The programming environment is Debian system, python3.9.2, Pyqt5 5.15.2.

For example, if I use pyqt5's **QPainter** to display images, I only need to implement it in **paintEvent**, which is what I said without signal transmission. Indeed, this statement is not accurate.

I am currently putting the **QLabel** method of displaying video images in real time into **QThread** to run. But this method takes up a lot of CPU. After testing, the code QPixmap.fromImage runs for a long time.

```py
class CommunicationWorker(QObject):
    start_communication_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CommunicationWorker, self).__init__()
        self.res_queue = args[0]
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.qp_cache = {}
        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView()
        self.frame_list = [None, None, None, None]
        self.label_list = args[1]

        self.running = False
        self.start_communication_signal.connect(self.run_thread)

    @staticmethod
    def play_hologram_frame(frame, show_label):
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        video_img = array2qimage(image)
        video_img = QPixmap.fromImage(video_img)
        show_label.setPixmap(video_img)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run_thread(self):
        self.running = True
        # hlg, front, back, enlarge = None, None, None, None
        while self.running:
            try:
                # Check for results
                for i in range(len(self.res_queue)):
                    temp = read_buffer(self.res_queue[i], i)
                    if temp is not None:
                        # self.play_hologram_frame(temp, self.label_list[i])
                        if i == 0:
                            self.frame_list[0] = cv2.resize(temp, (600, 720))
                        elif i == 1:
                            self.frame_list[1] = cv2.resize(temp, (600, 500))
                        elif i == 2:
                            self.frame_list[2] = cv2.resize(temp, (600, 500))
                        elif i == 3:
                            self.frame_list[3] = cv2.resize(temp, (1210, 720))
                        self.play_hologram_frame(self.frame_list[i], self.label_list[i])

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print(traceback.print_exc())

    def stop_thread(self):
        self.running = False
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is confusing. What do you mean by "do not need signals in the run method"? Please clarify your post, and provide more elements to understand the problem, because it's not even clear if the problem is just CPU usage (and to what extent and under what hardware/software situation) or if that affects the actual result in the GUI (slow response time, delays in image updates, etc.).

Comment: "But this method takes up a lot of CPU." - well, that's expected? CPU cores are there to be used. Do you have other problem like not enough FPS, UI thread blocking/glitching? I also don't see any kind of threads in your code, except function having name `run_thread`.  In Qt typically you can do heavy computations asynchronously (not necessarily in `QThread`), and only signal UI thread when the result is ready to display.